# LocalStorage does not allow me to save rich text fields

Tags: javascript, local-storage, summernote

I'm trying to persist form data into localStorage. For regular HTML fields like textboxes, this works perfectly. However I have a couple of rich text fields that don't seem to be able to save their data.

Razor markup for the field (I'm using MVC)

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Actions, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Actions, new { @class = "form-control", rows = "4" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Actions, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
</div>
```

HTML markup generated by the above:

```
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-md-2" for="Actions">Actions</label>
        <textarea class="form-control" cols="20" id="Actions" name="Actions" rows="4">
</textarea>
        <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-for="Actions" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
    </div>
```

Here is the code for saving / retrieving from local storage. I'm using exactly the same method for other fields and it works perfectly.

```
//save
localStorage.setItem('Actions', document.getElementById('Actions').value);

//restore
var Actions = localStorage.getItem('Actions');
document.getElementById('Actions').value = Actions;
```

I've tried using `document.getElementById('Actions').textContent` rather than `.value` - this seems to make it save correctly but I still can't restore the text. When I look at the `localStorage` object though it only reports the following text in my Actions field: `"<p><br></p>"`, unless using `.textContent`, in which case I see something like `<p>Test text<br></p>`

I am using [Summernote](https://summernote.org/) to provide rich text functionality and think this might be the cause of the issue but I'm not sure what to try. There are no errors reported in the console at all.

Comment: Try using `.innerHTML` instead.

Comment: That HTML markup you generate on its own is not a rich text editor. Summernote _adds_ additional elements in the DOM on top of that, to provide this functionality. From the examples on their site, it seems to be a div element inserted after the textarea, that provides the functionality here. I guess it could work by setting the value of the textarea, if you manage to get that done _before_ the Summernote functionality initializes itself for this field.

Comment: I figured it out, had to use summernote to insert the text. Initially I tried their text insert function but had to use one called code instead, like this: `$('#Actions').summernote('code', Actions);`. Works great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed this by using the following code

`$('#Actions').summernote('code', Actions);`

in place of

`document.getElementById('Actions').value = Actions;`

This puts the html code from the field directly into the summernote textarea with all formatting etc. I was also able to use `.actions` (`.innerhtml` didn't work)